# Unique background-image for each page in Nuxt

Tags: css, vue.js, sass, nuxt.js

as the title says i am trying to get a unique background-image for each page in my app.
Currently i have my background-image defined in `style/app.scss`.

```css
@import 'variables';
@import 'page_transition';
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans&display=swap');
body{
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;; // Globale font definitie
  background-image: url('../../static/background.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-color: $darkPurple;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

So far i've tried:

Dynamicly add the background url to the wrapper in the default layout.
**Result: the wrapper is not the body so it was not the result i was looking for.**

Added

```css
body {
  background-image: url('../../static/background.png');
}
```

in the `<style>` for each page with `scoped`. **Result: styling given to body is ignored.**
And also did the same but without `scoped`.
**Result: Each page had the same background.**

During these attempts i ofcourse commented the css line that defines the background in `style/app.scss`

Comment: Are the pages created dynamically? Or do you have a file in your pages directory for every page in your application? There’s different approaches you can take, depending on which scenario you’re facing.

Comment: Each .vue page is located in a directory specificly for pages.

Comment: Ok, now can you update your question with the code you used, where you attempted ‘defined the body background in the style for each page with scoped’, and also the content of your app.scss file. This would be very helpful :)

Comment: I've updated the question hopefully its clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside each page, set the background attributes of the body element within the `mounted()` hook.

Eg.

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'blue'
  }
}
```

Or for images, assuming you have an image files at `/static/images/bg1.jpg`.

```
export default {
  mounted() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('/images/bg1.jpg')"
  }
}
```

Remember you're manipulating the DOM directly when the `mounted()` hook is called on each page. If you exclude this method on any page, the background image won't change- it'll remain the same as the page you navigated from.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has been a problem for me for a while now.